# Forward notifications from Android to in car Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications

I'm trying to figure out how to send notifications from my phone to my cars stereo system.
The car uses the Blue&Me system. It can intercept and show SMS just fine, plus it has access to my contact book and call log.
I don't know where to start on how I can communicate with the Bluetooth in the car.
My hope is to send notifications to the Blue&Me and if thats not possible, perhaps mask it as a SMS message.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.